# AuditReader find method throws error (X is not an enum type)

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

In my application, an "`AuditReader reader`" is declared.
At some point, I'm trying to retrieve a BO with the method `reader.find(MyBO.class, id, lastRevision)`.

The thing is, this method throws a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`, the `detailMessage` being "`myBOenum is not an enum type`".

The main information I can provide is that this code hasn't been touched and was working perfectly with *Hibernate 4*, but it now throws this error if I switch to *Hibernate 5*. 
Reversing to *Hibernate 4* solves the issue.

Any idea what's wrong and how to fix this issue?

Edit: it seems that I have random errors... Maybe something about multi-threading? Here is one stacktrace I keep having now:

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This web container has not yet been started
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1674)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:399)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:394)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:393)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateMethod(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.lang.Class.getEnumConstantsShared(Class.java:3320)
    at java.lang.Class.enumConstantDirectory(Class.java:3341)
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:232)`

I have Java 8 update 161.
I've also found some similar issues I believe like here
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12396
But I couldn't get a solution from that page

Comment: please provide code and the complete stack trace.